# Spring WebContentInterceptor is not adding cacheSeconds to header

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, cache-control

I am trying to add configuration in spring mvc so that my static contents like js, images will be cached by browser. I have add the following in dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans>
.............
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean id="webContentInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
            <property name="cacheSeconds" value="31556926"/>
            <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true"/>
            <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"/>
            <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>
</beans>
```

But i still dont see the caching is enabled. I see the following in the browser debugger where it says Cache-Control:"no-cache".

[image: Firefox Debugger]

Please help !!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use mvc:resources for caching static files.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/public-resources/" 
       cache-period="31556926"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

Comment: I have tried both the methods specified by Burak Keceli and @Brian Clozel, and none of the them works. I somehow dont get the cache-control header value, very strange.

Currently i have specified this setting in dispatcher-servlet.xml  along with context. Should i specify this in a seperate beans xml?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the [`cacheMappings` property](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/WebContentInterceptor.html#setCacheMappings-java.util.Properties-) to configure path patterns / cache directives.

```
<bean id="webContentInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
  <property name="cacheSeconds" value="31556926"/>
  <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true"/>
  <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"/>
  <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true"/>
  <property name="cacheMappings">
    <props>
      <prop key="/static/**">2592000</prop>
    </props>
  </property>
</bean>
```

But indeed, Burak Keceli's answer is spot on; you'd better use `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.addResourceHandlers` or the XML configuration version with `<mvc:resources/>`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I added the interceptor but noting changed in the HTTP reponses.

In my case there was another spring context XML in my project where another `<mvc:interceptors>` was registered. It effectivly replaced my WebContentInterceptor configuration. Combining them solved it.

Perhaps something similar is going on in your configuration Abdus Samad...